# Windows 8 (Store App) in C - How to disable gzip compression?

Tags: c++, windows-8, http-headers

I have an app that appears to enable `gzip` encoding by default while sending data to the server.

We tried disabling the `gzip` compression by explicitly using:

`IXMLHttpRequest2::SetRequestHeader(L"Accept-Encoding", L"")` (on the HTTP Request Object, of course)

This still doesn't seem to help. Is there anyway to disable GZIP being enabled in the HTTP-Request headers from the C++ App?

Thanks!

Comment: gzip compression for reducing data transferred on mobile devices seems useful, so what problem are you really trying to solve, and think that disabling gzip is the best way? Maybe starting there is better and the best solution is not to disable gzip but something else...

Comment: In addition to what @PlasmaHH said: moreover the server itself may decide to honor or not your requests (SO, for example, will reply to some queries only with compressed data, regardless to what you _ask_).

Comment: I am also a bit confused about that you say the app sends gzip, and you put Accept-Encoding into the request header. But isn't that field only to tell the server what the client accepts?

Comment: @PlasmaHH: (1) Thanks for the comments! Enabling gzip with this proprietary server seems to add 30 second latency to request / response path. Hence the attempt to remove gzip. (2) You are correct.

Comment: @Adriano: Yes - I agree. Just want to reduce the huge latency gzip adds to the tx/rx path. The big issue is that, I am unable to find the documentation that would disable HTTP from enabling gzip, deflate in the http headers in Windows 8.

Answer (score 1):

To *ask* a server to do not use a specific encoding you should provide a list of `Accept-Encoding` values. From section 14.11 of [RFC2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616) (HTTP/1.1) you see that it has one of forms (values are examples):

```
Accept-Encoding: compress, gzip
Accept-Encoding:
Accept-Encoding: *
Accept-Encoding: compress;q=0.5, gzip;q=1.0
Accept-Encoding: gzip;q=1.0, identity; q=0.5, *;q=0
```

> If the content-coding is one of the content-codings listed in  Accept-Encoding field, then it is acceptable, unless it is  by a qvalue of 0. (As defined in section 3.9, a  of 0 means "not acceptable.")

Then to *ask* the server to do not use `gzip` compression you should provide, instead of an empty string, this value for `Accept-Encoding`:

```
gzip;q=0
```

This will require the server to do not use it and but you have to provide another encoding. See section 3.5 for available encodings. Use the quality `q` parameter to inform the server about your preferences (do not forget that if it can't provide that encoding for your request it'll reply with error 406).

```
identity;q=1.0, gzip=0.5
```

In this way you ask to use `identity` encoding and, in case it's not available, you can accept a `gzip` encoding too (this will prevent the server to reply with an error if it, for any reason, can't use any other encoding for your request). You may try performance of other encodings too (`compress` and `deflate`, for example).

**Code**
Then, finally, you have to use `IXMLHttpRequest2::SetRequestHeader(L"Accept-Encoding", L"identity;q=1.0, gzip=0.5")`. In [SetRequestHeader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh831168.aspx) you see that it's an *append* to headers sent by default so if you specify an empty string actually the value won't be changed (actually how it is interpreted may depends on the server, I didn't find any proper specification about this, you may inspect both your HTTP request and response to check what is actually sent/received).

Old value: `Accept-Encoding: compress`
Call: `IXMLHttpRequest2::SetRequestHeader(L"Accept-Encoding", L"")`
New value: `Accept-Encoding: compress`